# DirectShow - How to overlay video with text

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, directshow

I am writing an application for Windows Mobile where I want to display some text over the video preview on the screen.

Does anyone know how this could be done or if there's any good tutorial about it?

Thanks!

Comment: How far have you got so far? What issues have you come across so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/directx/article.php/c1229

Not sure if it applies to Windows Mobile, though.